# Company Servers Unable to Communicate Between One Another (On Same Network)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, network-share, share

I want to make sure and provide as much detail as possible to try to get this resolved or at the very least, figured out. If you need more information, please let me know and I will happily provide it.

Our servers are located within an external data center/colo (not sure if this has any bearing on the issue or not but wanted to include just in case). There are a few physical Windows servers connected via a network switch. Each physical server then has multiple virtual servers within it.

Our main server (VM) SERVER-A hosts all documents and information needed for employees to do daily duties. SERVER-A then needs to access and save data from SERVER-C (VM) to SERVER-B (VM).

Usually, this works without issue. But then there are times where SERVER-B and SERVER-C are unable to access SERVER-A and visa versa. All servers are on the same network and should be able to communicate with one another.

- SERVER-A is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and a domain controller
- SERVER-B (and older server, we are trying to get upgraded and moved over) uses ‘shared’ folders from SERVER-A and SERVER-C.
- SERVER-C (Windows Server 2016) has mapped network drives from both SERVER-A and SERVER-B.

We remote into SERVER-B via RDP connection using admin account (another thing we are wanting to change), pull reports, etc., and save to SERVER-A (until recently when it started producing errors when attempting to access SERVER-A folders).

We remote into SERVER-C via RDP connection, also using the admin account (again, trying to get this changed eventually), pull logs, etc. and save to SERVER-A. We also have an automated task running on SERVER-A that runs a script to generate and pull the logs from SERVER-C and saves them in a specified folder on SERVER-A. The last time this task ran successfully was 5/29, just to give an idea of how long we have been having this issue this time.

When attempting to access drives mapped from SERVER-C on SERVER-A, we receive a “Network Error – the network path was not found”. Nothing has changed, no paths have changed, mapped drives worked previously.

- I can ping SERVER-B from SERVER-A and can ping SERVER-A from SERVER-B. But can’t access ‘Shared’ folder(s) between the two.
- When pinging SERVER-C from SERVER-A, receive ‘Destination Host Unreachable’.
- When pinging SERVER-A from SERVER-C, receive ‘Request timed out’.

What would cause this to work sometimes, but not others? Is there a way to fix this? Does anyone have any suggestions that would help us bypass this issue or eliminate the issue altogether?
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: welcome, Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. see also [ask] but it's a good start